# Have logger's error message when not expecting any in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In one of my spec, I have the following expectation:

```rb
expect(Rails.logger).not_to receive(:error)
```

The problem is when it fails, I have no useful information about the error itself:

```
     Failure/Error: expect(Rails.logger).not_to receive(:error)
     
       (#<ActiveSupport::Logger:0x000000000b85dfa8 @level=1, @progname=nil, @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x000000000b85df08 @datetime_format=nil>, @formatter=#<ActiveSupport::Logger::SimpleFormatter:0x000000000b17f510 @datetime_format=nil, @thread_key="activesupport_tagged_logging_tags:93059720">, @logdev=#<Logger::LogDevice:0x000000000b85deb8 @shift_period_suffix=nil, @shift_size=nil, @shift_age=nil, @filename=nil, @dev=#<File:/home/circleci/myproject/log/test.log>, @mon_owner=nil, @mon_count=0, @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x000000000b85de40>>, @local_levels=#<Concurrent::Map:0x000000000b85dda0 entries=0 default_proc=nil>, @thread_hash_level_key=:"ThreadSafeLogger#96661460@level">).error(*(any args))
           expected: 0 times with any arguments
           received: 1 time with any arguments
```

Is there a way to get the content of the error somehow?
Should I change the way I write the spec to get it in case of failure?

It seems in my case the odd part is `received: 1 time with any arguments`, where I was expecting something like `received: 1 time with arguments: ("foo")`.

Comment: I think you should change another way to assert error. eg: ```expect { raise "oops" }.to raise_error(RuntimeError, "oops")```

Comment: I'm not trying to assert an error here, I'm trying to assert the absence of error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find how to do that in the rspec documentation, but here's an idea of how you could access the error information:

```
allow(Rails.logger).to receive(:error) { |params| raise params.to_s }
```

It is not as idiomatic but your test breaks when `error` is called on the logger

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hacky, but you can make a deliberately failing test in order to see information about the error itself

```
expect(Rails.logger).to receive(:error).with('foo')
```